# Find function that minimizes the distance from $f$ to $g$ with respect to the $L_2$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let H be the Hilbert space $L_2([-1,1])$ with the standard inner product:
$$\langle f|g \rangle=\int_{-1}^1 \bar{f}(x)g(x)dx$$ and define the functions, $f_n$, $n=0,1,2,3,...,$ on $[-1,1]$ by
$$f_n(x)=x^n$$
We have that $f_n$ belong to $H$. Now we let $g \in L_2([-1,1])$ be given by:
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{for }0\leq x \leq 1 \\
0, & \text{for }-1 \leq x<0
\end{cases}$$
And now I have to argue that there is a function in $U=\operatorname{span}\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ that minimizes the distance to g with respect to the $L_2$-norm and explicit find this function.

I'm not sure how to do that? Can anyone help me? I have found an expression for the inner product $\langle f_n, f_m\rangle $ for for all values of n, m, and I have found a orthonormal basis for $U$. If these can be used to solve the problem...?

Comment: Just compute $\|f_n-g\|$ for $n=1,2,3$ and pick the smallest. Not much arguing there.

Comment: Do you think Lifeni might have meant that $U = \langle f_1, f_2, f_3 \rangle$, i.e. the subspace generated by $f_1, f_2,$ and $f_3$?

Comment: Sorry I just forget to write "span", I have edited it now. I will try to do what @ 
copper.hat has wrote

Comment: The set $U$ is a closed convex set (in fact a subspace).

Comment: I'm not sure now. So I can use the hint that you has wrote first while it is the span?

Comment: Forget my first comment, that was before you added the span. Are you are aware of the result that there is a point in $U$ that minimises the distance to $g$?

Comment: One way would be to orthonormalise the $f_k$ (the Legendre polynomials) and then project $g$ onto $U$. If $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are orthonormal and span $U$ then let $g^* = \sum_k \langle p_k, g \rangle p_k$, note that $g-g^* \bot g^*$.

Comment: I'm not project  onto   while U is span of functions?

Comment: @copper.hat. I'm still confused what you mean. Can you maybe write it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways of approaching this problem, here is one.
There are a number of details to be completed, this purpose is to illustrate the idea.

If you orthonormalise the $f_n$ using Gram Schmidt you get the following: (cf. the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality_and_completeness) $P_n$).

$p_0(x) = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$, $p_1(x) = \sqrt{3 \over 2} x$,
$p_2(x) = \sqrt{5 \over 8} (3x^2-1)$, $p_3(x) = \sqrt{7 \over 8} (5 x^3-3x)$.

Let $\gamma_k = \langle p_k, g \rangle $ (the components of $g$ along $p_k$). Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\|g-\sum_k \alpha_k p_k \|^2 &=& \|g-\sum_k \gamma_k p_k+ \sum_k \gamma_k p_k -\sum_k \alpha_k p_k \|^2 \\
&=& \|g-\sum_k \gamma_k p_k+ \sum_k (\gamma_k - \alpha_k ) p_k \|^2 \\
&=& \|g-\sum_k \gamma_k p_k \|^2 + \| \sum_k (\gamma_k - \alpha_k) p_k \|^2 \\
&=& \|g-\sum_k \gamma_k p_k \|^2 + \sum_k |\gamma_k -\alpha_k|^2
\end{eqnarray}
In particular, this shows that the closest member of $U$ to $g$ is
given by $g^*=\sum_{k=1}^3 \gamma_k p_k$.

My computations give
$g^*(x) = {1 \over 32} (45x-35x^3)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand the argument. I have tried to make the calculations but I get $g^*(x)=\frac{1}{32}(45 x-35 x^2))$ and not the same as you. I think that $\langle p_2| g \rangle$ is zero, so we can not get something with $x^2$?

Comment: It is quite possible I made a mistake.

Comment: @Lifeni Yes, I had made a mistake, it should have been 45.

Comment: And also $x^3$ in stead of $x^2$. Thank you very much, that makes sense